# Django templates lookup order

Tags: django, templates, path, django-floppyforms

I'm writing an app, that uses `django-floppyforms`. Also, my app provides the default `twitter bootstrap` skin, so i have customized floppyforms templates im my app to make them bootstrap alike. I put `floppyforms/{layouts, rows}/bootstrap` into my app's templates directory. But it does not work: django won't use them. So, i don't want to enforce end user to put customized templates into his project, in fact, i want to point django to take my local `floppyforms` templates when it renders in-app content. I just want to make my app standalone without any unhandy depencies.

## UPDATE

Now i'm having the similar troubles with [django-admintools-bootstrap](https://github.com/buttscicles/django-admintools-bootstrap) and `Django 1.5.1`. It was added before `admin_tools` in `INSTALLED_APPS`, but there's no effect. Also it won't collect static for `django-admintools-bootstrap`. In other similar projects using this two packages and Django 1.4, all works fine. Also, i've checked the release notes for Django 1.5 for template lookup order changes and found nothing about it.

Answer (score 8):

Updated answer:

As of Django 1.8, [`TEMPLATE_DIRS`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/#template-dirs) and [`TEMPLATE_LOADERS`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/#template-loaders) are deprecated and replaced by [`TEMPLATES`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/#templates).

An example of [`TEMPLATES`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/#templates) can be:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [
            os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates'),
        ],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
            # 'loaders': [
            #     'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
            #     'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
            # ],
            'debug': True,
        },
    },
]
```

The template lookup order is by dictated by the following:

- Essentialy the most important place is the [`loaders`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/templates/api/#loader-types) option of the [`OPTIONS`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/templates/#django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates). If this is defined, it requires that [`APP_DIRS`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/#app-dirs) is not set and follows any explicit order there.
- If no loaders, and if any [`DIRS`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/#dirs) defined, these have priority as the `filesystem` loader.
- If no loaders, and [`APP_DIRS`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/#app-dirs) is defined, these have second priority over [`DIRS`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/#dirs).

The above are not explicitly documented, but can easily be deducted by the existing documentation and maybe after some experiments.

Answer (score 3):

If they are not in apps template directory, add absolute path of your templates directories in [`TEMPLATE_DIRS`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#template-dirs) settings.
These directories will be searched in order, so add them in front.

If they are in apps directory, you may want to put `'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader'` ahead of anyone in `TEMPLATE_LOADERS` setting.

Also, check how you are using template names while specifying templates. You should use as `'floppyforms/layouts/bootstrap/template1.html'`.

More info at [template loaders](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#module-django.template.loader)

Comment: floppyforms templates are in the app template directory, so i moved `'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader'` to the top of the `TEMPLATE_LOADERS`. Full path looks like '<my_app>/templates/floppyforms/layouts/bootstrap.html'. It still does not work. Also, if i put floppyforms templates into the project's template path, loader finds them.

Comment: @lilo.panic, what path do you use to specify template?

Comment: I just want to point, that I don't specify any path for floppyforms: when i create an instance of  `floppyforms.Form` in a view, `floppyforms` use the custom templates to render it. When i render my *own* view, i use path, i.e. `<myapp>/themes/default/index.html`

Comment: I had a similar problem where I put my templates in a nested folder inside of templates and Django couldn't find them unless the folder name was in the template name string.