# Django: Template Does Not Exist Error

Tags: python, django

In My django app I have a view called 'StatsView' given below:

```
class StatsView(LoginRequiredMixin, View):
    login_url = '/signin/'

    def get(self, request, template='app_folder/ad_accounts/pixel_stats.html', *args, **kwargs):
        #Code
        return render(request, template, context)
```

`app/urls.py`

```
url(
    r'^ad_accounts/(?P<ad_account_id>[^/]+)/pixel_stats',
    StatsView.as_view(),
    name="pixel_stats"
),
```

**template**
`pixel_stats.html`

```
<p> test</p>
```

However when I go to `localhost:8000/ad_accounts/acctid/pixel_stats/` I keep running into a `Template DoesNotExist Error`. I cant seem to figure out where Im going wrong. Ive added a bunch of URLs and havent run into this issue for any one them.

My app structure is as follows:

```
project/
  app/
    templates/
      app_folder/
        ad_accounts/
          pixel_stats.html
    views/
      ad_accounts/
        stats.py
```

Comment: Your template path does not seem correct given your directory structure.

Comment: All previous urls and templates follow the exact same structure and did not throw this error

Comment: Try `template='app/templates/app_folder/ad_accounts/pixel_stats.html'` or `template='app_folder/ad_accounts/pixel_stats.html'`. If it doesn't help, please show a similar URL that works.

Comment: my bad, in the view the template is already setup as `template='app_folder/ad_accounts/pixel_stats.html'`. I just corrected in the post

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/a/36312587/1332509 Also please show a URL that works. Is there any template URL that works?

Answer (score 0):

Silly mistake. Solved it by adding a `$` at the end in my `url`.

```
url(
    r'^ad_accounts/(?P<ad_account_id>[^/]+)/pixel_stats/$',
    StatsView.as_view(),
    name="pixel_stats"
),
```